# How to group text column by date in this pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this dataframe of tweets collected with the date they were posted. I would like to know if there is any way to group these tweets by date?

For example all tweets from one day X would be on the same line in the dataframe

[image]

Comment: `df.groupby('Date')`...something. You have to define "on the same line". You want them joined by spaces? commas? Get the daily total? How do you want the summary DataFrame to look?

Comment: I would like to separate with spaces. It's possible?

Comment: Yes. `df.groupby('Date', as_index=False)['Tweet'].apply(' '.join)`

Comment: Works! Thanks :)